# The package system is broken Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I am not able to install anything. I'm getting a message saying that i must check if I am "using third party repositories" and if so to disable them.
Where do i check that?
It also tells me to run `apt-get install-f` in a terminal, But i have no experience running commands in a terminal.
the message also tells me that the error was

> Error: BrokenCount>0

It all came with a NO ENTER sign that i now always in the top panel.
Thanks

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16.06. There is 16.04 LTS (which is still supported) and 16.10 (which has passed end of life). Which version are you running?

Comment: that was a typo, im running 16.04

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install -f` will remedy the 'broken package' issue. You must run it with elevated rights, hence the [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) prefix to the command which provides you with elevated rights as if you were the root user.

Once you've done that, launch the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) (in the System menu), then select Settings, Repositories. Pick all the third-party repositories, and delete them.

Comment: IM sorry, that im so ignorante, but what does it mean to "run it with elevated rights" ? I really have no experience with terminal , but want to be better. I know that i have to type first sudo, and then enter my pasword. But if i enter after the  apt-get install -f i get a message back saying that install -f is not a command. thank you for your patience.

Comment: @KAK the full command to run is `sudo apt-get install -f`.  Open the Terminal, type that in, and run it.  They mean by 'run with elevated rights' that you need to use `sudo` so that it runs as the system administrator and not in user-level directory space

Comment: I managed to run the command in the terminal. it worked. But i dont find the synaptic package manager in System Menu. Strange. Is there a other way for me to delete the Third-party repositories?

Comment: Look in all programs